# Is there a built-in/gem function to generate a logarithmic range in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Before I start writing one I was wondering if anyone knows of a built-in function or a gem that is able to generate a logarithmic range in Ruby (preferably hidden inside an enumerable object like Range), something like Matlab's [`logspace` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/logspace.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gem: http://mikiobraun.github.com/jblas-ruby/doc/classes/JBLAS.html#M000026 (untried).

Comment: Hmmm, JRuby wrapper so I'm guessing it doesn't work with standard Ruby.  Good find though, thanks.

Comment: In the case of logspace() the implementation is pure Ruby and self contained.